# Zipline Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_csv'

Tags: python, python-2.7, zipline

I just installed Zipline on Windows 10, Python 2.7 system using `conda`. When I [tried to use a function `fetch_csv` from `zipline.api`](http://www.zipline.io/appendix.html?highlight=fetch_csv#zipline.api.fetch_csv), I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_csv'
```

Why can't I load the function `fetch_csv`?

```
from zipline.api import fetch_csv

fetch_csv('./test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Zipline API reference](http://www.zipline.io/appendix.html?highlight=fetch_csv#zipline.api.fetch_csv) says that this methods is to "Fetch a csv from a remote url". For local files, I would suggest [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
pandas.read_csv('./test.csv')
```